# Get index on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am trying to develop a 2 player checkers game, for my college, but I am stuck at getting the index of the 2D array when I click on the piece.

I divided my HTML code in:

- table - the game board
- row - each row is the height of the array
- cell - each cell is a piece and the width of the array

Then I setted a default array to start the game:

```
  var board = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
    [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
  ];
```

Where the:
 - 0 - empty cell
 - 1 - Player 1 pieces 
 - 2 - Player 2 pieces

To get the position I am using this code

```
function getPosition() {
  $('.row').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $('.row').index(this) );
  });
  $('.cell').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $('.cell').index(this) );
  });
}
```

Get the height array position which should be between 0 and 7 are ok, but the cell from the row should be between 0 and 7 too, but using this I am getting from 0 to 63, using this parameters I have no idea how to start the next comparisons of the game.

Here is the code from codepen
http://codepen.io/michaelthompson/pen/jVdrav

Comment: change to `console.log( $('.cell', this.parentElement).index(this) );` to get the index within the current row

Comment: or `$('.cell').index(this) % 8`

Answer (score 4):

In each instance you can simply use `$(this).index()` which will return the index within the element's siblings

But since clicking on a row  always means clicking a cell you could combine them and do

```
$('.cell').on('click', function() {
   var $cell = $(this),  
       columnIndex = $cell.index(),
       rowIndex = $cell.parent().index();
});
```

---

What `$('.cell').index(this)` is doing is taking the whole collection of the class within the page and that's why you are getting 0-63

Comment: Did this answer help you? If so, feel free to accept it